# Render JavaScript variable in HTML as part of a Liquid template

Tags: javascript, liquid, dynamics-365

I would like to read a query string in JavaScript, and then modify the link that will be rendered in HTML, however I am rendering the HTML as part of liquid loop. So am not sure how I would read the query string in JavaScript, store the value of query string in a variable, and show it in the html that's rendered as part of a liquid loop.

I am still new to Liquid so any help would be appreciated. I am using this as part of Dynamics 365 portals.

Comment: can you give some specifics? you would probably have to pass the query string as part of the locals in order to use it - you wont be able to use something from the javascript runtime (window.location) in a serverside templating language (liquid)

Comment: Thanks @DaveAnkin .. so I am going from one page to the other. The target page as a query string of ID, this ID is the ID of a record. I want to use this record in HTML, to add it as an attribute to some html elements. Those HTML elements are rendered on the page as part of a loop in Liquid. What do you mean to pass the query string as part of a local? Do you have any example about time, sorry never heard of it.

Comment: okay so you have a select query and it returns an array, suppose its `[{ ID: 1, name: 'alice bio' },{ ID: 2, name: 'bob bio' }]`, and you render this into `<ul id="bios"><li><a data-id="1" href="/bio?ID=1"></a></li><li><a data-id="2" href="/bio?ID=2"></a></li></ul>` then you can do `$('#bios').find('a').data('id')` to get the first `data-id` out. I would need to review the exact jquery api, but is that what you want in terms of making the data available to js? https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: or is your question literally about this part https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/

Comment: to get them all out using that technique: `Array.from($('a', $('#bios'))).map(e => $(e).data())`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could just use javascript to make an html element then edit that element as you wish in javascript via

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myVar");
//Use var x to edit this element here

//OR 
var x = document.createElement("myVar");
//Use var x to edit this element here
```

document.getElementByID is only used if your element is already made in html, where document.createElement is used if you'd like to make a new element rather than using one thats already made.

Comment: How would that help me with the HTML generated in Liquid?

Comment: @BR1 You could just use the elements that liquid generates for example if liquid generates an element called "myVar" then you'll use document.getElemenyByID("myVar");